# fancybox: display long caption in multiple lines with the same width as the large image?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using Fancybox 2.1.5 to display a popup window with a large image. Here is the html:

```
<div class="webmedia">
    <a href="my-large.jpg" class="click-magnify" title="A very long caption, wider than its image">
        <img src="my-small.jpg" width="283">
    </a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('.click-magnify').fancybox({
 });
```

When the popup is displayed, the caption extends wider than the large image. I hope to display the caption in multiple lines with the same width of the large image.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try changing the *title* `type` like :

```
$(".click-magnify").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**